# boot2docker windows network interfaces

Tags: virtualbox, boot2docker

I am having a hard time setting up docker via boot2docker (v1.5.0, virtualbox v4.3.20) on windows.

The first installation failed because the daemon did not come up on the vm. So i uninstalled Virtualbox and Boot2Docker. After a reinstall the machine starts up correctly.

I want to use boot2docker for a google app engine managed vm, so i need to setup the environment variables for it (well the boot2docker shellinit does not work since it uses export which should be set on windows). So it set them manually.

```
DOCKER_HOST=tcp://192.168.59.103:2376
```

The IP Address is the one which i get by calling `boot2docker ip`. It is available on the machine itself as eth1.

If i try to connect (icmp) to the machine from my host it fails since there is no route to the virtual machine. The Virtual Network device (there is no other virtual network adapter) on my Windows 8.1 host looks like this (sry for the german version):

```
   Beschreibung. . . . . . . . . . . : VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter
   Physische Adresse . . . . . . . . : 08-00-27-00-54-98
   DHCP aktiviert. . . . . . . . . . : Nein
   Autokonfiguration aktiviert . . . : Ja
   Verbindungslokale IPv6-Adresse  . : fe80::bcb5:aa66:d0ce:25c4%30(Bevorzugt)
   IPv4-Adresse  . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.56.1(Bevorzugt)
   Subnetzmaske  . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Standardgateway . . . . . . . . . :
```

My guess would be that this device should get an ip address from the virtualbox's ip range like `192.168.59.x`

I found a workaround by setting a port forward on the NAT device, but this results in some other problems.

Am i doing it wrong? Is this a bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently there are some issues with the Google Managed VMs on boot2docker.

I found a solution which worked for my Ubuntu 14.04 machine as well as for my windows 8.1 machine. The step by step guide can be found here: https://gist.github.com/xuru/604da3c02ec96904d352

The most crucial part seems to be the dowload of a certain version of the image:

`boot2docker download --iso-url=https://github.com/boot2docker/boot2docker/releases/download/v1.3.3/boot2docker.iso`